# Intelligent hachure detection in ArcMap / QGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2

I have a DXF file containing residential and commercial buildings as well as the property lines. After importing it to ArcMap (10.2.1) I get something like this:

[image: buildings]

Now I want to:

1. Seperate the buildings from the property lines (which sometimes run through buildings)
2. Differ between residential (45 degree hachure) and commercial / other buildings (all other hachures)

To fulfill task 1 I already converted the polylines (each building originally consists of at least 4 lines + lines for hachure) to polygons and tried to aggregate them. But the result is always only one big polygon instead of many smaller ones.

Can anybody help me with this issue?

**EDIT:**

The result should look something like this (without the red patterns):

[image: modified image]

I just found another version of the DXF file which has two layers: one for the property lines and one for the buildings. So the property line problem is solved. But: All buildings are included in one layer and can't be differed by an attribute.

Comment: Can you publish a picture where you would explain how exactly some of the problematic areas will look like after editing (+how many polygons will be there, will they keep attributes if they have any etc)?

Comment: How are the layers separated in your DXF? Is it all in one layer? If not, you could probably get pretty far with FME. If not, you still could get somewhere with FME, I'd suspect.